# Standard c# method to determine if type has nested values?

Tags: c#

I am wondering whether there is a way (maybe a standard method) to whether a given type has nested fields, or if it just a value 'by itself'.

To be clear what I mean by nested types, is types that contain other values (lists, arrays, objects, other more or less complex datastructures).
By 'values by themselves' I just mean any type that does'nt contain other types, such as strings, int, boolean, char, long, double etc.

If I have to conjure up the signature for a specific method, the usecase would be something like this:

```
string s = "some text"
bool b = isNested(s)
```

Would return false, because, a string does not have nested variables inside of it.

```
int i = 2;
bool b = isNested(i);
```

Would also be false, because a int does not contain nested variables.
However:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
bool b = isNested(array);
```

Would be true, because inside of an array, there are nested values.
If we make an object:

```
var ob = {inside = "lorem", AlsoInside = "ipsum"};
bool b = isNested(i);
```

Would also return true, because the object ob contains nested variables

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: What would be the input of the method?  Dynamic? You can perform JSON encode and count the levels. Your question does not provide enough information to be answered.

Comment: Your edit makes things much more clear. However, what exactly have you tried?

Comment: that's the thing, I don't really know where to start

Comment: I won't give you the answer, only some hints. What you need is a method that can accept any type, you need to determine the type of the value passed and then compare the type against a list of known types (there's no "native" way to do what you want)

Comment: Thanks a lot! am I able to program to the "any" interface? I'm having some real difficulties finding an overview over c#'s type and class hierachies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to check if the type of a value is a primitive or if it does have fields. The method might look like this:

```
public static bool IsNested(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }
    Type t = value.GetType();
    if (t.IsPrimitive) {
        return false;
    }
    FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                     BindingFlags.Public | 
                                     BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (fields.Any()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

First you check the [`IsPrimitive` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=net-5.0) to check all the basic types. After that you check if there are any instance fields in the class. If there are, then you know it's nested. You can use this method like this:

```
public class EmptyClass {
}
public class OnlyPropertiesClass {
    public int Whatever {get; set;}
}
public class OnlyFieldsClass {
    public int foo;
}
public static void Main()
{
    object[] values = new object[] {
        "abc",
        'c',
         4, 
         3.14,
         false,
         new EmptyClass(), 
         new { id = 4 },
         new OnlyPropertiesClass(),
         new OnlyFieldsClass(),
         new {},
         Guid.NewGuid()
    };
    foreach (object value in values) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Value: {value}, IsNested: {IsNested(value)}");
    }
}
```

This will generate an output like this:

```
Value: abc, IsNested: True
Value: c, IsNested: False
Value: 4, IsNested: False
Value: 3.14, IsNested: False
Value: False, IsNested: False
Value: Testing.Program+EmptyClass, IsNested: False
Value: { id = 4 }, IsNested: True
Value: Testing.Program+OnlyPropertiesClass, IsNested: True
Value: Testing.Program+OnlyFieldsClass, IsNested: True
Value: { }, IsNested: False
Value: 59865879-3cee-41ae-bc09-539ef8059279, IsNested: True
```

Notice: `string` is a nested type because it has the fields [`m_stringLength`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,c9004774b2325e35,references) and [`m_firstChar`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,c9004774b2325e35,references). Depending on how you want to handle arrays, you need to use [`Type.IsArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isarray?view=net-5.0) and check the length with [`Array.Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isarray?view=net-5.0).